# How to create multiple instance of block in Swift?

Tags: swift, block

I have defined a block which return after `webservice` call.

```
typealias Receive  = ([AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void

func method(_ paramter: paramter, block:@escaping Register){
   //some code
}
```

And I have called this method from `appDelegate.swift`.

```
handler.shared.method(_ paramter) { (isGranted, token, error) in
   //some code
}
```

This is working as expected.

Now If I call the same method from `viewcontroller.swift` The block enters only in viewcontroller after getting response.

I want to to create multiple instance of the same block so that when I get response it should enter appdelegate's as well as viewcntroller's background block.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish with this? After a webservice request you usually don't want some block to fire in a completely different class, what problem are you really trying to solve? [Smells like an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you really must fire two separate blocks of code from a single web response, you can [broadcast a notification](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/broadcasting-with-nsnotification-center-8bc0ccd2f5c3), [open a channel](https://theswiftpost.co/using-channels-in-swift/) or simply expose the code you want to execute in a method and call it in two places.

Comment: @kevin thanks for the quick reply.This is requirement of the project.If you can share a snippet that will be very much helpful

Comment: I can't provide a snippet if I don't know what you want exactly. Could you update the question with your specific use-case and some example code? Just write out some pseudo code to show what you want to happen, then someone here can tell you what you need to do to make it work.

Comment: Why are you talking about Swift code being in a `.m` file? `.m` is for Objective-C. Swift uses `.swift`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good idea to do that but as you insist, please follow following code.

You can add blocks into `whereToPassData` and whenever you get the response notify to all.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class AppGlobalManager:NSObject {
    static let sharedManager = AppGlobalManager()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
    }

    var whereToPassData:[Register?] = []

    typealias Register  = ([AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void

    func method(_ paramter:Any, block:@escaping Register){
        //some code
        for ref in whereToPassData {
            ref?(["test":"test"])
        }
        self.whereToPassData.removeAll()
    }
}

public class yourvc :UIViewController {
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        var block = { (test:[AnyHashable : Any]) in
        }

        AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.whereToPassData.append(block)
        AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.method(for: "test")
    }
}
```

Comment: worked for my condition .thanks for the quick help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would chain the response from method. When my app delegate needs data, have your view controller continue the response. In the example below, the success parameter is chained to provide retries. But you could pass entire responses with this block parameter pattern.

```
func pull(data: @escaping ((_ response: String, _ success: Bool) -> Void)) {
  let code = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? true : false
  let response = (code ? "pulled some data" : "incomplete data")
  data(response, code)
}


func someButtonTapped(needsRecall: ((_ outerSuccess: Bool) -> Void)?) {
  pull { (response, success) in
    if let checkRecall = needsRecall { checkRecall(!success) }
    if success {
      print(response)
    } else {
      print("failed to pull data")
    }
  }
}

someButtonTapped { (needsRecall) in
  if needsRecall {
    someButtonTapped(needsRecall: nil)
  } else {
    print("success")
  }
}
```